# LINQ to read and format XML file then create text file

Tags: c#

```
I got this XML file:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<textTables xmlns:xsi="http"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../texttables.xsd" language="en-US" name="Texttabellen">
    <description>Version: 2020-01-08 --- Automatisch generiert: Wed Jan 08 09:54:17 CET 2020 --- Copyright (c) Volkswagen AG</description>
    <textTable name="DTC-table" version="1-00-000">
        <description>Anzeigetexte zu den Fehlercodes nach VAG bzw. SAE Konvention</description>
        <history>
            <historyInfo date="" author="" version="1-00-000">
                <description></description>
            </historyInfo>
        </history>
        <constraints maxChars="63" maxLines="2"/>
       <text id="U180300">
            <line>Steuergerät für Anzeige Lichtlinie 4</line>
            <line>keine Kommunikation</line>
        </text>
        <text id="U180400">
            <line>Steuergerät für Anzeige Lichtlinie 5</line>
            <line>keine Kommunikation</line>
        </text>
        <text id="U180500">
            <line>Pumpe für Tankentlüftung.</line>
            <line>unplausibles Signal</line>
        </text>
        <text id="U303300">
            <constraints obd="true" obd-key="U303300"/>
            <line>Steuergerät für Zugang- und Startberechtigung</line>
            <line>Zertifikat fehlt oder ungültig</line>
        </text>
        <text id="default">
            <line>Not found</line>
        </text>
        <text id="none">
        <line>Search key</line>
        </text>  
</textTable>
</textTables>
```

I would like to have an output like this:
U180300 Steuergerät für Anzeige Lichtlinie 4 keine Kommunikation

This is what I have so far in my code:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            //Load xml
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

            //Run query
            var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("text")
                       select new
                       {
                           Header = lv1.Attribute("id").Value,
                           Children = lv1.Descendants("line")
                       };

            //Loop through results
            foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
            {
                result.AppendLine(lv1.Header);
                foreach (var lv2 in lv1.Children)
                    result.AppendLine("     " + lv2.Attribute("text").Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

After the file is formatted, I would like to save it as a text which is why I'm using stringbuilder. I'm open to other approaches on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Here a working method to do the work:**

```
    public List<string> GetFormatDataLines()
    {
        List<string> allResults = new List<string>();

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        //Load xml
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(PATHTOFILE);
        foreach (var element in xdoc.Descendants("text"))
        {
            result.Append($"{element.Attribute("id")} ");
            var lines = element.Elements("line");
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                result.Append($"{line.Value} ");
            }
            allResults.Add(result.ToString());
            result.Clear();
        }

        return allResults;
    }
```

**And here the method to save what you have red in a text file:**

```
    public void SaveResult(List<string> results, string pathToSave)
    {
        var filesStream = File.Create(pathToSave); //Create or overwrite existing file
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            byte[] toWrite = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(result + "\n");
            filesStream.Write(toWrite, 0, toWrite.Length);
        }
    }
```

---

**This is how the list with the elements looks like:** 
[image]

**And this is how your text file should look like after you saved it:** 
[image]

Comment: The picture at the end is not adding to your solution. It is more rainsing questions, like why are all the `ä` miss-spelled as `?`.  Is this because you have a bad text-editor? Or is your answer not correctly dealing with the character set (UTF-8) ?

Comment: @Luuk It is because of the `ASCII` encoding... In order to make it work properly you will need to change it to `Unicode`. I already edited my answer. Thanks for your comment